# Get list of frequently used programs

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm making an application that will collect some information on the user computer for statistical reasons, eg. What programs are installed, does it use wired\wireless connection, default browser, Does it use ms office, open office, other?, etc.
I want to know what are the most used programs on the computer. I know windows keeps track of that, because if you go to the control panel->add\remove programs. You can see if a program is used frequently, rarely or occasionally.
This info must be stored in the registry, but I just can't seem to find it.

Does anyone know where it is?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I don't know where it is, but I wouldn't trust it. I've seen programs that I use daily reported as used "rarely". Equally, programs I installed months ago and haven't touched since reported as used "frequently".

Answer (score 0):

What it shows in add remove programs is not accurate. There is plenty of programs that does this, but they all check for running proccess.

You can get all the information your looking for via WMI.

Comment: there is a infitie number ( close to at least ) number of WMI classes, many of them getting duplicate information. You sadly have to research a bit, to find out how you want your program to work. Only using WMI will be very bad for preformance ( WMI can be very slow).